# Using SQLSRV_FIELD_METADATA is there a way to return full name data types, like VARCHAR or INT?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2000, sqlsrv

Dear intelligent people of the internets,

Using SQLSRV on SQL Server 2000 I'm trying to echo out the column data types and lengths using the SQLSRV_FIELD_METADATA function but only a number is passed which represents the data type.

**Here is the code:**

```
  echo '<pre>';
  echo '<ul>';
    foreach( sqlsrv_field_metadata( $stmt ) as $fieldMetadata ) {
        foreach( $fieldMetadata as $name => $value) {
           echo "<li>$name: $value</li>";
        }
        echo "<br/>";
    }
  echo '</ul>';
  echo '</pre>';
```

**Here is a snippet of the output:**

```
Name: UNITID
Type: 4
Size: 
Precision: 10
Scale: 
Nullable: 0

Name: STOCKNUMBER
Type: 12
Size: 30
Precision: 
Scale: 
Nullable: 1
```

**Is there a way to convert Type: 4 and Type: 12 into the actual name of the column?  So instead it would return Type: INT, and Type: VARCHAR.**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could implement your own type map. [Here's a list of values on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136906%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Comment: The list of values has 2 duplicates in it, namely -2 and 3 both have two descriptions - any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Esorteric, thanks for the tip.  I've implemented a function that acts as a type map as suggested:

```
  function returnType($value) {
    switch ($value) {
        case 4:
            return "(4) SQLDMO_DTypeInt4 :: Signed integer data. The width of the integer is four bytes.";
            break;
        case 12:
            return "(12) SQLDMO_DTypeVarchar :: Variable-length character data.";
            break;
        case 93:
            return "(93) SQLDMO_DTypeDateTime4 :: ODBC SQL_TIMESTAMP_STRUCT.";
            break;
        case 5:
            return "(5) SQLDMO_DTypeInt2 :: Signed integer data. The width of the integer is two bytes.";
            break;
        case -6:
            return "(-6) SQLDMO_DTypeInt1 :: Unsigned integer data. The width of the integer is one byte.";
            break;  
        case -1:
            return "(-1) SQLDMO_DTypeText :: Long, variable-length character data.";
            break;                      
    }     

  }
```